# Getting error when sending form -unexpected token s in json at position 0

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, nodemailer

I am doing for the first time a contact form through Node with Nodemailer where you send the contact form through the website and it goes straight to your inbox.

So my app.js on the public folder is like this:

```js
const form = document.getElementById('contact-form');

const formEvent = form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  let mail = new FormData(form);
  sendMail(mail);
});

const sendMail = mail => {
  fetch('https://coopza-testing.herokuapp.com/send', {
    method: 'post',
    body: mail,
  }).then(response => response.json());
  
};
```

And on my server.js file is

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const multiparty = require('multiparty');
require('dotenv').config();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

// instantiate an express app
const app = express();
// cors
app.use(cors({ origin: '*' }));
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
  );
  next();
});


app.use('/public', express.static(`${process.cwd()}/public/index.html`)); // make public static

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  port: 587,
  auth: {
    user: process.env.EMAIL,
    pass: process.env.PASS,
  },
});

// verify connection configuration
transporter.verify(function(error, success) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Server is ready to take our messages');
  }
});

app.post('/send', (req, res) => {
  let form = new multiparty.Form();
  let data = {};
  
  form.parse(req, function(err, fields) {
    console.log(fields);
    Object.keys(fields).forEach(function(property) {
      data[property] = fields[property].toString();
    });
    console.log(data);
    const mail = {
      sender: `${data.name} <${data.email}>`,
      to: process.env.EMAIL, // receiver email,
      subject: data.subject,
      text: `${data.name} <${data.email}> \n${data.message}`,
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mail, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).send('Something went wrong.');
      } else {
        res.status(200).send('Email successfully sent to recipient!');
      }
    });
  });
});

// Index page (static HTML)
app.route('/').get(function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(`${process.cwd()}/public/index.html`);
});

/** ********************************************** */
// Express server listening...
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}...`);
});
```

When I send the form it comes with the errors :

```js
unexpected token s in json at position 0
POST https://coopza-testing.herokuapp.com/send 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I tried in the json, response with

```js
 .then(res => res.text()) // convert to plain text
    .then(text => console.log(text));
```

But no more info could get from it.

I would be much appreciated some knowledge of yours, please

Comment: I guess the error is coming from the call at `transporter.sendMail`. Also, can you log the `mail` object in the console and see if that is having some bad data that JSON is not able to parse it?

Comment: It seems that is not fetching anything because nothing comes from the log...Just keeps with the same error

Comment: can you try `JSON.parse(mail);` before calling the `transporter.sendMail` and see if it gives an error?

Comment: @Hiren I did and it return the error : Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0... I am lost now :D

Answer (score 0):

"unexpected token s in json at position 0" error comes in when you try to parse object which can't be converted to JSON.

for ex :

```
let str = 'Test string';
console.log(JSON.parse(str)). --> will throw an error.
```

Just try to console it. Also try to use debugger or console to check till where the code is executing without errors, you can see through it.

```
let form = new multiparty.Form();
  let data = {};
  console.log(form);
  form.parse(req, function(err, fields) <- this parsing could be a problem
```

Comment: It doesn't log anything...It just seems that the app.post it is not doing nothing...

Comment: Fetch request won't fail actually even if you have 500 or 404. May be your post route is not called or you are not setting up the headers. Please check this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch and try to set headers. Also, use async await to wait for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following code and see if you get something useful in the console?

```
app.post('/send', (req, res) => {
  let form = new multiparty.Form();
  let data = {};
  
  form.parse(req, function(err, fields) {
    if (err) {
       console.error('An error has occurred while parsing the form', { err });
    }

    console.log({ fields });
    Object.keys(fields).forEach(function(property) {
      data[property] = fields[property].toString();
    });
    console.log({ data });
    const mail = {
      sender: `${data.name} <${data.email}>`,
      to: process.env.EMAIL, // receiver email,
      subject: data.subject,
      text: `${data.name} <${data.email}> \n${data.message}`,
    };

    // for debugging purpose, check what values `mail` object is having
    console.log({mail});

    // check to see if this is causing the trouble??
    console.log({json: JSON.stringify(mail)});

    transporter.sendMail(mail, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Error while sending the email', err);
        res.status(500).send('Something went wrong.');
      } else {
        res.status(200).send('Email successfully sent to recipient!');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Also, I have a question for you, why are you using the `multiparty` module for parsing data as json object, can't you use a simple `app.use(express.json(options));`? As you're just using the form to get the JSON value for sending textual data, then you could have used `express.json()` instead of multiparty.